# Scene transitions to Game on host, but not on player client

Tags: unity, c#, multiplayer, mirror-networking

I've been following Mirror tutorials on Youtube, where there was a transition between a lobby scene and a game scene, I wanted to add a loading scene inbetween them. The issue is the game transitions only on host but not on player. So the host gets into the game scene while player stays in the loading scene. Tested out this behaviour on builds and in editor, only host can access the game. I transition through a button with command:

**NetworkRoomPlayerLobby.cs:**

```
    [Command]
    public void CmdStartGame()
    {
        if (Room.RoomPlayers[0].connectionToClient != connectionToClient) { return; }

        Room.StartTransitionScene();
    }
```

then it  gets into the NetworkManagerLobby script and transitions the scene there:

**NetworkManagerLobby.cs:**

```
    public void StartTransitionScene() //sets scene to loading scene
    {
        if(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().path == menuScene)
        {
            if (!IsReadyToStart()) { return; }

            ServerChangeScene("Loading");
        }

        StartGame();
    }


    public override void ServerChangeScene(string newSceneName)
    {
        if(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().path == loadingScene && newSceneName.StartsWith("Game"))
        {
            for (int i = RoomPlayers.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) //converts room players to game players
            {
                var conn = RoomPlayers[i].connectionToClient;
                var gameplayerInstance = Instantiate(gamePlayerPrefab);
                gameplayerInstance.SetDisplayName(RoomPlayers[i].DisplayName);

                NetworkServer.Destroy(conn.identity.gameObject);

                NetworkServer.ReplacePlayerForConnection(conn, gameplayerInstance.gameObject);
            }
        }
        base.ServerChangeScene(newSceneName);
    }

    public void StartGame()
    {
        ServerChangeScene("Game"); //change the scene to game scene
    }
```

The gameplayerInstances are not found in the Game scene. Could that be correlated?

Added a method for starting the game,I have two things on my mind that are causing the issues and I boiled them down to this:

1. The override method checks the condition before the scene is loaded hence issues with the game scene
2. Durring the transition(Lobby => Loading => Game) there is potential object destruction